# TeamFoundation.VersionControl.HatPackage failed to load

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm getting this error in VS2013 when loading a project under source control:

Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.HatPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' failed to load.

HOWEVER, unlike all the other posts about this there is NO config file to delete under

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0
\Cache

The folder is simply empty.  I tried repairing the whole installation as well

Comment: Are there other version numbers here: "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\" - v4.0 for example?

Comment: Yes, there's a 4.0, but its empty too

Comment: I am having same issue? Did you rectify it?

Comment: i too have same issue

Comment: This broke with a windows update for me, but got working with deletion of VersionControl.config

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue after I installed Update 4 for VS 2013 (I have Premium edition)

The Team explorer / source control Explorer were drawing blanks.

After a couple of wasted hours (I was avoiding uninstall/re-installing),
I could resolve this issue after I re-installed the Team Explorer for VS 2013. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40776

Comment: It's work on my VS2013, Update 5. This must be an answer. Thanks.