# After upgrading to visual studio 2013 update 3 TFS no longer works

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, azure-devops

After upgrading to Visual Studio 2013 update 3 all TFS components are broken.  If I open the pending changed window it states

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005):  Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been...
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsShell5.LoadPackageWithContext...

If I try to open any solution bound to tfs I get an exception :

Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.HatPackage,
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl, 
Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' failed to load

An exception is thrown for each project and then none of the projects will load for the solution making it unusable.

Trying to sign into VS Team Services doesn't work either.  Nothing happens when you click sign in.

Has anyone else had this problem?  I have tried repairing the install and that didn't work either.

Comment: Have you just upgraded the version of VS running on your desktop? Do you have a TFS build agent running on the same machine as the broken VS installation? Have you also upgraded TFS to 2013.3?

Comment: Just visual studio.  There isn't any installation of TFS locally on this system.  The TFS instance I'm connecting to is Visual studio online so I would assume its compatible.

Comment: You're correct VS 2013.3 and VS online should be compatible. I was expecting you to be running TFS of some sort on the same machine as VS. Is `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a` in the GAC?

Comment: Yes there are three versions of that component in the GAC.  A version 10, 11 and 12.  I have visual studio 2010, 2012 and 2013 installed on this machine.  I did install update 3 on another computer with just 2013 installed and it is working fine but I would like to figure out whats going on before wiping it clean and starting over.

Comment: Whats strange is when I try to open a project it states : "This version of visual studio .NET does not support source controlled projects.  Any changes that you make to this project will not be propagated to source control.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TeamFoundation.VersionControl.HatPackage failed to load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23787029/teamfoundation-versioncontrol-hatpackage-failed-to-load)

Answer (score 2):

Ok I figured out the problem.  When I googled visual studio update 3, the first item takes you to microsofts download site for update 3 which I guess is only good for the basic version of visual studio.  I am using visual studio 2013 ultimate which has a separate download for update 3.  After installing the update 3 for the ultimate version it is now working.  The other system that I installed it on was a professional version which is why it might have worked there.